# Disable Right Click context menu - still getting it on Chrome's title bar

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, right-click, titlebar

I'm trying to avoid users to use the back button, it was so far so good, until I try to get the context menu, right clicking over Chrome's title bar I've seen other pages that doesn´t have the same options I do.

I used this code:

```
    < script type="text/javascript">
        function disableBackButton() {
            window.history.forward(1);
        }
        setTimeout("disableBackButton()", 0);
        window.oncontextmenu = function() { return false }

    </ script>

< script type="text/javascript">

    if (typeof window.event != 'undefined')
        document.onkeydown = function() {
            if (event.srcElement.tagName.toUpperCase() != 'INPUT')
                return (event.keyCode != 8);
        }
    else
        document.onkeypress = function(e) {
            if (e.target.nodeName.toUpperCase() != 'INPUT')
                return false;
        }

</ script>

< script type="text/javascript">
    document.onkeydown = chkEvent
    var formInUse = false;

    function chkEvent(e) {
        var keycode;
        if (window.event) keycode = window.event.keyCode; //*** for IE ***//
        else if (e) keycode = e.which; //*** for Firefox ***//
        if (keycode == 8) {
            return false;
        }
    }
</ script>    
< body onload="disableBackButton();"  >
```

It seems to me that there is not much to do and that's OS territory, but worth a try if someone knows about this

Kind Regards

George

Comment: Users hate it when you miss with their back button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely CANNOT and MUST NOT be allowed to do anything outside your webpage sandbox. Even if you accidentally find a way in some browser to do that, do not rely on it, as it is will be viewed as huge security risk and promptly patched or reduced to some hidden-flag activated kludge by developers. Just drop the idea as it stands completely against what browser's sandboxed environment tries to accomplish, so it won't work in any public project.